# Map C-like packed data structure to Rust struct

Tags: string, rust, mapping, structure

I'm fairly new to Rust and have spent most of my time writing code in C/C++. I have a flask webserver that returns back a packed data structure in the form of length + null-terminated string:

```py
test_data = "Hello there bob!" + "\x00"
test_data = test_data.encode("utf-8")
data = struct.pack("<I", len(test_data ))
data += test_data
return data
```

In my rust code, I'm using the `easy_http_request` crate and can successfully get the response back by calling `get_from_url_str`. What I'm trying to do is map the returned response back to the `Test` data structure (if possible). I've attempted to use `align_to` to unsuccessfully get the string data mapped to the structure.

```
extern crate easy_http_request;
extern crate libc;

use easy_http_request::DefaultHttpRequest;
use libc::c_char;

#[repr(C, packed)]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Test {
    a: u32,
    b: *const c_char  // TODO: What do I put here???
}

fn main() {
    let response = DefaultHttpRequest::get_from_url_str("http://localhost:5000/").unwrap().send().unwrap();
    let (head, body, _tail) = unsafe { response.body.align_to::<Test>() };
    let my_test: Test = body[0];
    println!("{}", my_test.a); // Correctly prints '17'
    println!("{:?}", my_test.b); // Fails
}
```

I'm not sure this is possible in Rust. In the `response.body` I can correctly see the null-terminated string, so I know the data is there. Just unsure if there's a way to map it to a string in the `Test` structure. There's no reason I need to use a null-terminated string. Ultimately, I'm just trying to map a data structure of size and a string to a Rust struct of the similar types.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? I guess you are just printing the pointer address. Instead, use `CStr::from_ptr` to construct a `CStr`. https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr

Comment: @PeterHall, it seems like it's printing the pointer address... It prints 0x6874206f6c6c6548 when executing `println!("{:?}", my_test.b)'`. I added a new line of `let my_str = unsafe { std::ffi::Cstr::from_ptr(my_test.b) };` to attempt your recommendation, but my IDE (Visual Studio Code) throws an exception at that line, of Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @fowlball1010: that 0x6874206f6c6c6548 are the first few bytes of your array interpreted as a pointer value, not a pointer to the string: 0x48 is the `H`, 0x65 is the `e`... Your string simply resides at `&result[4..]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are confused by two different meanings of `pack`:
* In Python, `pack` is a protocol of sorts to serialize data into an array of bytes.
* In Rust, `pack` is a directive added to a struct to remove padding between members and disable other weirdness.

While they can be use together to make a protocol work, that is not the case, because in your pack you have a variable-length member. And trying to serialize/deserialize a pointer value directly is a very bad idea.

Your packed flask message is basically:

- 4 bytes litte endian value with the number of bytes in the string.
- so many bytes indicated above for the string, encoded in utf-8.

For that you do not need a packed struct. The easiest way is to just read the fields manually, one by one. Something like this (error checking omitted):

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

let a = i32::from_le_bytes(response[0..4].try_into().unwrap());
let b = std::str::from_utf8(&response[4 .. 4 + a as usize]).unwrap();
```

Comment: I'm really wanting to do the equivalent of "casting" the return data from flask directly into a well-defined struct. In C, I've done this several times before using the above flask code with a structure that has a zero byte character array, such as struct Test { DWORD dwSize; CHAR data[0] }. With the returned data in memory, a direct cast to Test would then allow me to access data as a null terminated string via a struct (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).

Comment: @fowlball1010: Ah, but that is tricky. First you have the alignment issue, you have a byte array, but you want it to be `DWORD` aligned, and `align_of` is not the tool for that. Then you have the zero-length array thing, that AFAIK cannot be directly converted to Rust. I think that you are better off doing the destructure manually, that is what Python's `struct` does after all. Or maybe using Serde, that is always fun...

Comment: @fowlball1010: In fact, this struct is just a variable length array of utf-8 validated bytes that carry its length. And in Rust there is already a type that does exactly that, that is `str`.

Comment: I would follow this answer. There are no ways to implement what you want in a safe way with some "direct" casting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use raw pointers, they are [unsafe to use](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html?highlight=raw,pointer#dereferencing-a-raw-pointer) and recommended only when there are strong reasons to
get around Rust’s safety guarantees.

At minumum a struct that fits your requirement is something like:

```
struct Test<'a> {
    value: &'a str
}
```

or a `String` owned value for avoiding lifetime dependencies.

A reference to `&str` comprises a len and a pointer (it is not a C-like `char *` pointer).

By the way, the hard part is not the parsing of the wire protocol but to manage correctly all the possible
decoding errors and avoid unexpected runtime failures in case of buggy or malicious clients.

In order not to reinvent the wheel, an example with the parse combinator [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom):

```
use nom::{
    number::complete::le_u32,
    bytes::complete::take,
    error::ErrorKind,
    IResult
};
use easy_http_request::DefaultHttpRequest;
use std::str::from_utf8;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Test {
    value: String
}

fn decode_len_value(bytes: &[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], Test> {
    let (buffer, len) = le_u32(bytes)?;

    // take len-1 bytes because null char (\0) is accounted into len
    let (remaining, val) = take(len-1)(buffer)?;
    match from_utf8(val) {
        Ok(strval) => Ok((remaining, Test {value: strval.to_owned()})),
        Err(_) => Err(nom::Err::Error((remaining, ErrorKind::Char)))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let response = DefaultHttpRequest::get_from_url_str("http://localhost:5000/").unwrap().send().unwrap();
    let result = decode_len_value(&response.body);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```